# filling array with joblib Parallel

Tags: python, multiprocessing, joblib

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import numpy as np

n = 10
l = np.random.randn(n,50)
a = np.zeros(n)

def myfun(i):
    for k in range(5):
       a[i] = np.correlate(l[0],l[i])[0]

Parallel(n_jobs=6,max_nbytes='50M')(map(delayed(myfun), range(n)))

>> a
  array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

Why is array `a` not being filled?

Answer (score 1):

The `a` array inside of `myfun()` that is being modified is not the same array as the `a` array outside of that function.  I don't know what the Parallel call does, but it seems that it copying the `a` array and your function operates on the copy.  Maybe it clones the entire global environment.

Here's a simplified version of your code that makes what I'm saying more clear (I tried adding the `global` call hoping that would fix it, but nope):

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import numpy as np

n = 10
a = np.zeros(n)
a[1] = 33

def myfun(i):
    global a
    a[2] = i
    print(a)

Parallel(n_jobs=6,max_nbytes='50M')(map(delayed(myfun), range(n)))

print()
print(a)
```

Result:

```
[ 0. 33.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0. 33.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0. 33.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0. 33.  3.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0. 33.  4.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0. 33.  5.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0. 33.  6.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0. 33.  7.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0. 33.  8.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0. 33.  9.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]

[ 0. 33.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
```